# Arbitrary In-Page Content Snippets

Tags: hugo

I'd like to include such things as a call-to-action 'offers' (a title, a paragraph and button link), in most of my pages. Since there are potentially multiple offers at a time, I was thinking of defining an 'offer' content type, as I also want an /offers page, however, I don't need nor want the individual node page views.

Given this model, is there a way I can select individual offer content and render it on arbitrary  pages in my page templates?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that I can achieve this with a combination of configuring [build options](https://gohugo.io/content-management/build-options/#render) to prevent the creation of the physical pages, and using [GetPage](https://gohugo.io/functions/getpage/) in combination with a partial, in order to obtain the content itself.